# Should an API be focused more on caching to improve response times, or on lowering the number of requests required?

Tags: caching, architecture

So, we have an API which has a large amount of cacheable items, such as articles and products, but every item can have user-specific data attached to it, such as favourites and specific, calculated values, and it already allows filtering and sorting on each list GET endpoint. You need to authenticate before accessing the API.

We have current 2 different styles of retrieving data in the API:

- With blog posts, we get back the blogs together with the user-specific is_favourite and friends_favourited data. This isn't cached as it's unique to every user.
- With store products, we get back the products from one endpoint, and the favourite products from a different endpoint, allowing us to cache the products.

The time has come to unify these and we're not sure which way to go. Is it more important to **lower the number of requests** (reducing caching and possibly increasing server costs), **or** is it better to **have cacheable data** (increasing response time and hopefully server costs at the expense of multiple requests)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no better ways.

If clients requests some apis always together, then maybe reasonable to create combined api for one request instead many requests.

If clients requests some apis separately, then caching will be better.

But these ways are not mutually exclusive. We use all mechanisms in our API for speed increasing.

In your example, products have own cache,  but user data may to have cache too, for each user, and events that change user data, may to invalidate cache .And your api just combine data from two caches with some logic.

Comment: Damn, I was really hoping for a single answer :) I suppose our problem is not knowing what the future holds, so we can only vaguely predict how future apps may use our API